# Recursive error on polynomial multiplication

Tags: python, algorithm

For two day now I have been trying to compute polynomial multiplication  using Karatsuba method in python.

I am using this algorithmic steps and also this helper functions

1. If n = 1 or n = 2 solve the problem directly; Otherwise:
2. Construct four half-size polynomials a, b, c and d, of degree n/2 - 1, out of X and Y. Divide X up into parts, a and b, and divide Y up into parts c and d -- so a and c will have the low order
   coefficients (indices 0 through n/2 -1) of X and Y, and b and d will
   have the high order coefficients (indices n/2 through n -1).
3. Calculate the sums x' = a + b and y' = c + d -- note that x' and y' are also polynomials of degree n/2 - 1.
4. Calculate temp = x' . y' recursively.
5. Calculate ac, and bd recursively.
6. Let temp = temp - ac - bd;
7. Combine ac, bd, and temp, which are all polynomials of degree n - 1, into a new polynomial of degree 2n -1, placing ac in indices 0
   through n - 1, bd in indices n through 2n - 1, and adding temp to
   the values now in indices n/2 through 3n/2 -1. Notice that the
   highest coefficient will be 0.

```
def add(poly1, poly2):
    """Add two polynomials"""
    result = [0] * max(len(poly1), len(poly2))
    for i in range(len(result)):
        if i < len(poly1):
            result[i] += poly1[i]
        if i < len(poly2):
            result[i] += poly2[i]
    return result


def split(poly1, poly2):
    """Split each polynomial into two smaller polynomials"""
    mid = max(len(poly1), len(poly2)) // 2
    return  (poly1[:mid], poly1[mid:]), (poly2[:mid], poly2[mid:])


def increase_exponent(poly, n):
    """Multiply poly1 by x^n"""
    return [0] * n + poly
```

**my code**

```
def multiply_optimized(poly1, poly2):
    #step 1
    if len(poly1) <= 1 or len(poly2) <=1:
        return np.multiply(poly1,poly2).tolist()
    
    else:
        #spliting the polynomial into 4 half-size step 2
        A, B = split(poly1,poly2)
        a, b,= A
        c,d = B
        
        #recursively calculate ac,bd,and, (a + b, c + d)
        #step 5
        ac = multiply_optimized(a,c)
        bd = multiply_optimized(b,d)
        #step 3
        x,y = add(a,b),add(c,d)
        
        temp = multiply_optimized(x,y)
        
        print('This is ac: ',ac, 'This is bd',bd, 'This is temp:',temp)
        #step 6
        temp = temp-ac-bd

        
        return ac+bd,temp

poly1 = [2,3,9,4,5]
poly2 = [2,6,4,5,1,3]
multiply_optimized(poly1,poly2)
```

Expected Output
`[4, 18, 44, 84, 87, 100, 58, 56, 17, 15]`

I think I am getting it all wrong on step 3, 4 and 6 which resulted to

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-116-d2448c352e3e> in <module>
----> 1 multiply_optimized(x,y)

<ipython-input-115-e5282c0d225a> in multiply_optimized(poly1, poly2)
     14 
     15         x,y = add(a,b),add(c,d)
---> 16         ac = multiply_optimized(a,c)
     17         bd = multiply_optimized(b,d)
     18 

<ipython-input-115-e5282c0d225a> in multiply_optimized(poly1, poly2)
     15         x,y = add(a,b),add(c,d)
     16         ac = multiply_optimized(a,c)
---> 17         bd = multiply_optimized(b,d)
     18 
     19         temp = multiply_optimized(x,y)

<ipython-input-115-e5282c0d225a> in multiply_optimized(poly1, poly2)
     20 
     21         print('This is ac: ',ac, 'This is bd',bd, 'This is temp:',temp)
---> 22         temp = temp-ac-bd
     23 
     24 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

I understand what the error means but I just can't figure out the best possible solution for the above step 3,4,6

Comment: Please include the full error message including traceback. It makes tracking down the issue much quicker and easier. That said, it sounds like you've ended up with native Python lists instead of (presumably) the numpy arrays that you expected to be subtracting from each other.

Comment: also include a sample input, what do `poly1` & `poly2` look like? are they lists? are they strings? are they `np.array`?

Comment: @Kemp I just updated the code with full traceback and also the expected output is suppose to be a list not really an array

Comment: @DrBwts The input  and output is a list. I just updated the code with the input and output

Comment: I had a look & honestly you need to keep tighter control over your variable types. Some of them get interpreted as `np.int` some as `tuple` some as `list`. I recommend you rewrite and explicitly cast variables as the type you expect. Good luck.

Comment: @DrBwts Thanks for the update, I casted the array to list, so I think I have a single variable type which is `lnp.multiply(poly1,poly2).tolist()`.

right now I simple figure out how to calculate step `6` using the above algorithm.

Comment: If it's simple element-wise subtraction then, for example, to get `a - b` you can do something like `c = [x - y for x, y in zip(a, b)]`.